# only select one pie slice

Tags: dc.js

My name is Sol and I am new with DC javascript library.

My `dataTable` doesn't show only the selection I made with a pieChart. It shows the previous selection too.

This is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/SolPerez/kLdg3tte/

```
chart2
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .slicesCap(3)
    .innerRadius(100)
    .dimension(fruta)
    .group(sumGroup)
    .legend(dc.legend());

chart2.render();

table2  
    .dimension(fruta)
    .sortBy(function(d) { return d.name})   
    .order(d3.ascending)
    .group(function(d) {return d.name})
    // dynamic columns creation using an array of closures
    .columns([
        function(d) { return d.name},
        //function(d) {return d.unidad;},
        function(d) {return d.cnt;}

]);

table2.render();
```

I made a `pieChart` and a `dataTable` showing fruits and quantity. After the selection of a fruit, it shows the fruit.

But when I select another slice in the pieChart, the previous slice is still selected.

Why does the dataTable show the data for both slices? Why isn't the previous selection removed?

Comment: I don't understand - it appears to be working properly to me. Are you referring to the "Others" slice? This will hold all the categories that are not in the top 3 - by specifying `.slicesCap(3)` you've told the chart to show three slices, and group all the others.

Comment: Or do you mean that you only want to select one slice at a time? It's not hard to get that effect, but the default behavior is to toggle each slice in and out of the filter when you click on it.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! Yes, I only want to select one slice at a time, not a multiselect. I dont want to see the previous selection. How can I get that effect? Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I've linked an earlier question which is basically the same, and voted to close this. I think the Ethan solution will work with dc.js 2.1.* and the Xaser solution will work with dc.js 2.0.* and below.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon! I will read the solutions.

Comment: Than you Gordon. This solution works ok :-):  

myChart.addFilterHandler(function (filters, filter) {
    filters.length = 0; // empty the array
    filters.push(filter);
    return filters;
});